# Crontab task does not work, Linux, Debian

Tags: linux, debian, php, cron, crontab

At a Debian server I've set a crontab task using `crontab -e` with the following content:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php
```

**Why doesn't it work?**

When I run the same script in CLI it work perfectly: `php terra_swap_api.php`

### Notes

0. When I do `ls -l` in the usr/bin folder I see the following:
   `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root   21 Dec 15 18:28 php -> /etc/alternatives/php`.
   What does **php -> /etc/alternatives/php** mean ?
1. When saving in *GNU nano* it prompts to save into the **strange file name** like the following  `/tmp/crontab.AoPJy1/crontab`. Is it correct ?
2. Where can I see any logs of crontab runs/errors?
3. The script `terra_swap_api.php` does writing to a db.

### Update 1

After removing `root` off the crontab expression, nothing has changed:
`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php`

### Update 2 - System logs

System logs do have some trace any interaction with the file in mind.  Eg.   `Dec 24 16:52:01 clearthefog CRON[7530]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)`

The tail of 20 logs:

```
tail -f -n 20 /var/log/syslog
Dec 24 16:49:01 clearthefog CRON[7258]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)
Dec 24 16:49:01 clearthefog CRON[7259]: (root) CMD (   [ /etc/bind/named.conf -ot /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp ] || (date; touch /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp; sudo /root/dnsmgr/dnsmgrupdate) >>/var/log/dnsmgrupdate)
Dec 24 16:50:01 clearthefog CRON[7278]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/vesta/php/bin/php -d disable_functions="" /usr/local/vesta/softaculous/do_backups.php >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 24 16:50:01 clearthefog CRON[7279]: (admin) CMD (sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-rrd)
Dec 24 16:50:01 clearthefog CRON[7282]: (admin) CMD (sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-queue backup)
Dec 24 16:50:01 clearthefog CRON[7284]: (root) CMD (   [ /etc/bind/named.conf -ot /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp ] || (date; touch /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp; sudo /root/dnsmgr/dnsmgrupdate) >>/var/log/dnsmgrupdate)
Dec 24 16:50:01 clearthefog CRON[7283]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)
Dec 24 16:51:01 clearthefog CRON[7507]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)
Dec 24 16:51:01 clearthefog CRON[7509]: (root) CMD (   [ /etc/bind/named.conf -ot /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp ] || (date; touch /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp; sudo /root/dnsmgr/dnsmgrupdate) >>/var/log/dnsmgrupdate)
Dec 24 16:52:01 clearthefog CRON[7530]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)
Dec 24 16:52:01 clearthefog CRON[7532]: (root) CMD (   [ /etc/bind/named.conf -ot /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp ] || (date; touch /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp; sudo /root/dnsmgr/dnsmgrupdate) >>/var/log/dnsmgrupdate)
Dec 24 16:53:01 clearthefog CRON[7547]: (root) CMD (   [ /etc/bind/named.conf -ot /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp ] || (date; touch /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp; sudo /root/dnsmgr/dnsmgrupdate) >>/var/log/dnsmgrupdate)
Dec 24 16:53:01 clearthefog CRON[7548]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)
Dec 24 16:54:01 clearthefog CRON[7566]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)
Dec 24 16:54:01 clearthefog CRON[7569]: (root) CMD (   [ /etc/bind/named.conf -ot /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp ] || (date; touch /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp; sudo /root/dnsmgr/dnsmgrupdate) >>/var/log/dnsmgrupdate)
Dec 24 16:55:01 clearthefog CRON[7588]: (admin) CMD (sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-rrd)
Dec 24 16:55:01 clearthefog CRON[7589]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/vesta/php/bin/php -d disable_functions="" /usr/local/vesta/softaculous/do_backups.php >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 24 16:55:01 clearthefog CRON[7587]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)
Dec 24 16:55:01 clearthefog CRON[7593]: (admin) CMD (sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-queue backup)
Dec 24 16:55:01 clearthefog CRON[7592]: (root) CMD (   [ /etc/bind/named.conf -ot /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp ] || (date; touch /tmp/dnsmgrupdate.stamp; sudo /root/dnsmgr/dnsmgrupdate) >>/var/log/dnsmgrupdate)
```

Yet I can't figure out what might be a problem...

### Update 3 - it seems to be called

Examining the `var/log/syslog` file I indeed found that cron line called every minutes:

```
Dec 24 17:09:01 clearthefog CRON[10168]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)

Dec 24 17:10:01 clearthefog CRON[10188]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)

Dec 24 17:11:01 clearthefog CRON[10417]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)

Dec 24 17:12:01 clearthefog CRON[10435]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)

Dec 24 17:13:01 clearthefog CRON[10455]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)
```

Why then it **does not perform as it does in CLI**, **scraping and writing smth. in db** ?

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't it work?

Because there are two slightly different crontab formats, and you used the wrong one – there is no "username" field in per-user crontabs.

Only the *system* crontab at `/etc/crontab` has a "username" field, but the crontabs edited via `crontab -e` *don't* have one, as the whole crontab file already belongs to a specific user (selected using the `-u` option).

So in your case, the word `root` is being interpreted *as the command to run*.

> When I do `ls -l` in the usr/bin folder I see the following:
> `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root   21 Dec 15 18:28 php -> /etc/alternatives/php`.
> What does `php -> /etc/alternatives/php` mean ?

It's a *symbolic link* as the `l` character indicates, and the path following `->` is the link's *target*.

Debian allows several PHP versions to be installed side-by-side (e.g. `php8.0`, `php7.4`, `php7.0`) and has the "update-alternatives" system to choose which version should be the "primary" PHP version. It works by having a chain of symlinks that the "update-alternatives" points to one specific version.

```
                                           /usr/bin/php7.0
/usr/bin/php --> /etc/alternatives/php --> /usr/bin/php7.4
                                           /usr/bin/php8.0
```

> When saving in GNU nano it prompts to save into the strange file name like the following `/tmp/crontab.AoPJy1/crontab`. Is it correct ?

Yes, that's how the `crontab` tool works – it makes a temporary copy of the crontab for you to edit. When the editor exits, the 'crontab' tool moves the temporary file back into its regular location at /var/spool.

> Where can I see any logs of crontab runs/errors?

The system log is usually available through `journalctl -b` or `journalctl -b -u cron`.

It may also be available in the file `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: see **Update 1**.

Comment: see your system logs.

Comment: see **Update 2**.

Comment: see my **Update 3**. The crontab notation seems to be invoked, yet it writes nothing into db...

Comment: But that's a completely different path than the one you showed in your cronjob?

Comment: it's the real path, in my question I've originally omitted 2 folders for disguising reason. I'll update my question now.